# Вывод тегов bass.net в Label.Content

Tags: c#, wpf, bass.net

Во время проигрывания потока в момент смены трека на радио, происходит захват новых meta данных (Исполнитель и Название трека), как их вывести в *Label* (*textbox* и пр.) именно методом, а не нажимая кнопку *Play*.

```
using CSharp_Bass_Console;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Un4seen.Bass;
using Un4seen.Bass.AddOn.Tags;

namespace BandedSpectrumAnalyzer
{
    public class BassEngine : INotifyPropertyChanged, ISpectrumPlayer
{
    #region Переменные
    public int Bitrate;                                                                    ///Битрейт
    public int freq;                                                                       ///Частота дискретизации
    public string Channel;                                                                 ///Информация Канала
    public string Artist;                                                                  ///Исполнитель
    public string Title;                                                                   ///Трек
    public string Year;                                                                    ///Год выпуска трека
    public string NameStation;                                                             ///Радиостанция
    Dictionary<int, string> ChannelsDict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        {0, "Null"},
        {1, "Mono"},
        {2, "Stereo"}
    };               ///Частота дискретизации
    private static BassEngine instance;                                                    ///Singleton Instance (Чтобы класс BassEngene стал доступен в MainWindow )
    public int Stream;                                                                     ///Поток
    private bool isPlaying;                                                                ///Проигрывается
    private int maxFFT = (int)(BASSData.BASS_DATA_AVAILABLE | BASSData.BASS_DATA_FFT4096); ///Глубина анализа потока
    private int sampleFrequency = 44100;                                                   ///Частота дискретизации потока
    public static int volume;                                                              ///Громкость
    private TAG_INFO tagInfo;
    private SYNCPROC mySync, mySyncEnd;
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler<RPTagsChangedEventArgs> TagsChanged;
    public event EventHandler EndStream;

    public BassEngine()                                                                   ///Конструктор
    {
        Initialize();
        mySync = new SYNCPROC(MetaSync);
        mySyncEnd = new SYNCPROC(SyncEnd);
    }
    private void MetaSync(int handle, int channel, int data, IntPtr user)
    {
        OnTagsChanged(handle, channel, data, user);
        GetTagsFromURLStream();
    }
    private void SyncEnd(int handle, int channel, int data, IntPtr user)
    {
        OnEndStream();
        GetTagsFromURLStream();
    }
    public TAG_INFO TagInfo { get; private set; }
    public void OnTagsChanged(int handle, int channel, int data, IntPtr user)
    {
        EventHandler<RPTagsChangedEventArgs> handler = TagsChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            GetTagsFromURLStream();
            handler(this, new RPTagsChangedEventArgs(TagInfo, handle, channel, data, user));
        }
    }
        private void OnEndStream()
    {
        GetTagsFromURLStream();
        EndStream?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public static BassEngine Instance                                                      ///Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new BassEngine();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void Play(string url, int volume)
    {
        if (ActiveStreamHandle != 0)
        Bass.BASS_StreamFree(ActiveStreamHandle);
        Stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateURL(url, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        ActiveStreamHandle = Stream;
        IsPlaying = true;
        PlayCurrentStream();
        Bass.BASS_ChannelSetSync(Stream, BASSSync.BASS_SYNC_META, 0, mySync, IntPtr.Zero);
        Bass.BASS_ChannelSetSync(Stream, BASSSync.BASS_SYNC_META, 0, mySyncEnd, IntPtr.Zero);
        GetTagsFromURLStream();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (ActiveStreamHandle != 0)
        {
            Bass.BASS_ChannelStop(ActiveStreamHandle);
        }
        IsPlaying = false;
    }

    void GetTagsFromURLStream()
    {

        TAG_INFO tagInfo = new TAG_INFO();
        Bass.BASS_ChannelGetTags(Stream, BASSTag.BASS_TAG_META);
        BassTags.BASS_TAG_GetFromURL(Stream, tagInfo);
        TagInfo = tagInfo;
        NameStation = TagInfo.album;
        Artist = TagInfo.artist;
        Title = TagInfo.title;
    }

    public static void SetVolumeToStream(int stream, int vol)
    {
        volume = vol;
        Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(stream, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, volume / 100F);
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        IsPlaying = false;
        Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        WindowInteropHelper interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow);
        if (Bass.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_SPEAKERS, interopHelper.Handle))
        {
            BASS_INFO info = new BASS_INFO();
            Bass.BASS_GetInfo(info);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mainWindow, "Bass initialization error!");
            mainWindow.Close();
        }
    }

    private void PlayCurrentStream()
    {
        Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        WindowInteropHelper interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow);
        // Play Stream
        if (ActiveStreamHandle != 0 && Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(ActiveStreamHandle, false))
        {
            BASS_CHANNELINFO info = new BASS_CHANNELINFO();
            Bass.BASS_ChannelGetInfo(ActiveStreamHandle, info);
            sampleFrequency = info.freq;
            Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(Stream, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, volume / 100F);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mainWindow, "Что-то пошло не так");
            mainWindow.Close();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    public int ActiveStreamHandle
    {
        get { return Stream; }
        protected set
        {
            int oldValue = Stream;
            Stream = value;
            if (oldValue != Stream)
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ActiveStreamHandle");
        }
    }

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return isPlaying; }
        protected set
        {
            bool oldValue = isPlaying;
            isPlaying = value;
            if (oldValue != isPlaying)
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsPlaying");
        }
    }
    public int GetFFTFrequencyIndex(int frequency)
    {
        return Utils.FFTFrequency2Index(frequency, 4096, sampleFrequency);
    }

    public int GetFFTData(float[] fftDataBuffer)
    {
        return Bass.BASS_ChannelGetData(ActiveStreamHandle, fftDataBuffer, maxFFT);
    }
   }
   }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using BandedSpectrumAnalyzer;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using Just_me_default;

 namespace Just_me
  {
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
  { private string url;

    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleValue", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScaleValueChanged)));



    private static void OnScaleValueChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = o as MainWindow;
        if (mainWindow != null)
            mainWindow.OnScaleValueChanged((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
    }
    protected virtual void OnScaleValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {

    }

    public double ScaleValue
    {
        // IMPORTANT: To maintain parity between setting a property in XAML and procedural code, do not touch the getter and setter inside this dependency property!
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(ScaleValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ScaleValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string Album { get; private set; }
    public string Artist { get; private set; }
    #endregion
    public MainWindow()
    { 

        InitializeComponent();

        BassEngine bassEngine = BassEngine.Instance;

       /// UIHelper.Bind(bassEngine, "CanStop", StopButton, Button.IsEnabledProperty);

        spectrumAnalyzer.RegisterSoundPlayer(bassEngine);
    }
    private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate_1(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start((sender as Hyperlink).NavigateUri.ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    private void TagINFO()
    {
        NameStation.Content = BassEngine.Instance.NameStation;
        artist.Content = BassEngine.Instance.Artist;
        title.Content = BassEngine.Instance.Title;
    }
    #region Button Station
    private void record_chill_out(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/chil_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();

    }


    private void megamix(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/mix_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void pirate_station(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/ps_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void pump(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/pump_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void rave_fm(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/rave_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void record_breaks(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/brks_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void record_deep(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/deep_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void radio_record(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/rr_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void record_techno(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/techno_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void russian_mix(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/rus_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void trance_mission(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/tm_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void wkns(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://wknc.sma.ncsu.edu:8000/wknchq.ogg";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void vip_house(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/vip_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void yo_fm(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/yo_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void record_dubstep(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/dub_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void record_edm(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/club_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void future_house(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/fut_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void record_trap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/trap_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void minimal_tech(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/mini_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    private void gop_fm(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://air2.radiorecord.ru:805/gop_320";
        BassEngine.Instance.Play(url, BassEngine.volume);
        TagINFO();
    }
    #endregion

    private void SliderVolume(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
      BassEngine.SetVolumeToStream(BassEngine.Instance.ActiveStreamHandle, Convert.ToInt32(SlVolume.Value));
    }

    private void r(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NameStation.Focus();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: А в чём принципиальная разница, выводить по нажатию кнопки или по какой-то другой причине?

Comment: Дело в том, что после синхронизации тегов string Artist имеет новое значение ( новый исполнитель начал играть), а как это сообщить в Textbox, если он получил свое значение артиста когда мы нажали на нужную станцию. Т.е. textbox не знает, что пришло новое значение, пока мы снова не нажмем на кнопку

Comment: Ну отлично, а в чём сложность вывести в Textbox в нужный момент, после обновления артиста, а не по нажатию кнопки?

Comment: Не знаю, что и где писать. Если писать в классе где происходит вызов делегата, то оттуда нельзя вызвать объект, которому это присваивается. Можете привести пример?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить таймер, который будет во время произведения обновлять тэги через определённые промежутки времени.